# How to make the second timeout callback execute first?

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I want to let the funtion executed like this:
Input:People('Z').waitFirst(5)
after 5 seconds
Output://waited 5 s
       //I'm Z ~

```
function People(name) {
this.name = name;
setTimeout(console.log("I'm" +name+ "~"), 0);
return this;
}

People.prototype.waitFirst = function (time) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
    }).then(() => {
        setTimeout(console.log("waited" +time+ "s"), time * 1000);
   });

}
```

But I got error  **Uncaught TypeError: People(...).waitFirst is not a function(…)**
Where is the mistake?

Comment: Is your question about the error or about how to make the second timeout callback execute first? Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Your call is missing a `new`

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question.